# Given that A has an eigen decomposition ($A = \sum_{i=1}^n{\lambda_ix_iy_i^T}$) - prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n{x_iy_i^T} = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I'm facing a new area of math problems in linear algebra with the eigen decomposition.

The fact that $A$ has an eigen decomposition is given, so that:
$$A = \sum_{i=1}^n{\lambda_i x_i y_i^T} = \sum_{i=1}^n{\lambda_iE_i}  $$
also: $$y_i^Tx_i = 1 $$
whereas $x_i$ is an eigen vector from right (culomn), and $y_i^T$ is an eigen vector from left (line).

I also need to prove that for every vector $\vec{x}$ that's not an eigenector: $$ (xI-A)^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac{1}{x- \lambda_i}E_i}$$ But I get the feeling that the second part somehow depends on the first one.

I know that if $A$ has an eigen decomposition it means it has n eigenvectors, and it is similar to a diagonal matrix D. by the way the question is asked, I get the feeling $A$ itself is a diagonal matrix.

I tried adding multiplication with $y_i^T$ or with $x_i$ from the left or right and see how the fact that  $y_i^Tx_i = 1 $ serves me, but I really got to nowhere.

I really want to solve it myself, but this topic is clearly not 100% sunk down, so I'd appreciate a guidance to the solution.

Comment: for the first part $A = PDP^{-1}$ because it evidently is diagonalizable.  Now for notations reasons, assign $X := P$ and $Y:=P^{-1}$.  you know $I=XY$, but what if you compute $XY$ another way, say as a sum of rank one matrices. A similar idea for the second part -- carefully work through the factorization and write it as a sum of rank one matrices

Comment: can you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: partition $X$ by columns and $Y$ by rows and write out $XY$ as a sum of rank one matrices -- also sometimes referred to as the outer product form of matrix multiplication